# Como solicitar dados de entrada N vezes, e concatenar esses dados

Tags: python, string

Primeiro eu pedi ao usuário para digitar a quantidade de *links* que ele queria adicionar ao arquivo (nesse caso uma *string*), daí se por exemplo ele digitar 4, quero fazer a pergunta "Link de download: " quatro vezes para ele e adicionar todas as respostas para essa pergunta em uma *string*. Como faço isso?

Código:

```
c=input("Quantos links de download deseja colocar: ")
print("")
dw=input("Link de Download: ")
```

Daí ele pega cada resposta e acrescenta a uma *string* final como uma só *string*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer o laço é simples.

```
c = input("Quantos links de download deseja colocar: ")
print()
i = 0
texto = ""
while (i < int(c)):
    dw = input("Link de Download:")
    texto = texto + dw + "  "
    i = i + 1
    print()
print(texto)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/HIYYXT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ibchhxld-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/GetMultipleLinks.py).

Claro que esta implementação é bem simplificada, ela não fará nada muito útil, mas à partir dela você pode ir melhorando conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: Perfeito mano, só vou precisar fazer uns ajustes, mas esse código foi excelente, pois entendi tudo.. Só vou adaptar ao software.. Valeu mesmo

Comment: Voltando ao problema, o ruim é que ele fica reaproveitando a variável "texto" e daí grava só o ultimo link digitado e como faço pra adicionar essa string gerada no fim de outra string? Colocarei meu código em outro comentário, por organização

Comment: Estou usando `link = "[hide][url=" + dw + "][b]GSMFans-"+ nm + " - Link" + str(i) + "[/b][/url][/hide]"` para gerar o link.. daí como adicionar isso a uma outra string, e como fazer para não perder os links anteriores? Não posso usar listas pois os [] e vírgulas irão atrapalhar

Comment: Não, ele grava todos na string. Não fica muito organizado mas é o que eu falei, você vai ter que adaptar ao que você precisa. Eu até vou mudar um pouco porque tinha um errinho. Vou te dar uma dica, quando for fazer uma pergunta, coloque todos detalhes importantes nela. Agora você já está falando de outras coisas que não estavam na pergunta. De qualquer forma, eu posso tentar ajudar mais um pouco se eu entender qual seu problema.

Comment: Ah, desculpa eu entendi, no meu código eu não tinha colocado texto = texto ... ou texto += ... Por isso gravou apenas a última.. Então outra minha dúvida (que não deixei bem claro no tópico) é como adicionar o conteúdo dessa string texto em outra string que já tem um conteúdo.. Eu já tinha visto um código sobre isso, mas esqueci como e onde

Comment: É desta forma que eu usei aí no código. Você vai concatenando o que quiser o que quiser com o `+`, quando você não quer perder o conteúdo já existente, basta você usar a própria variável que deseja preservar o conteúdo como parte do novo resultado, como eue usei no código acima. Para não perder o conteúdo de `texto`, eu usei esta variável na concatenação, assim o novo valor de `texto` incluirá o que já tinha em `texto` antes.

Comment: Nossa  kk deu uma barbeirada aqui, é que é tanta coisa (estudo C, JavaScript e Shell também) daí da uma confusão ás vezes.. Valeu aí

Answer (score 3):

Você poderia usar o `for` porque no caso depois que o user digitar a quantidade de vezes que ele quer inserir os links você vai saber quantas vezes tem que repetir o laço, ai depois é só usar listas para armazenar os links digitados.Por exemplo:

```
links = []
quant_links = int(input('Quantidade de Links: '))

for i in range(quant_links):
    link = raw_input('URL do link: ')
    links.append(link)
```

Ai depois é só tratar os links inseridos.